# Flexbox child element width shrinking to 0

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flexbox horizontal scrollable div like this.

```
<div class="hz-panel">
   <div class="list-holder">
      <img src="abc.png" width="40"/>
      <p>Deals</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for the same

```
.hz-panel {
 background: #ffffff;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 display: flex;
 padding: 0 3%;
}

.hz-panel .list-holder {
      padding: 15px 13px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
 }
```

Works fine on my chrome browser and Android Marshmallow webview, the problem occurs on kitkat webview where the whole scrollable list gets collapsed on condensed (one over other) since the width of every list holder becomes Zero while the padding is there. How can I avoid this problem. The parent should grow based on its children divs content. One solution is to set the `min-width` of `list-holder` div to say `54px`. But there has to be a good way to avoid this.

Please Help.

Comment: I'm not even sure "kitkat webview" even supports flexbox - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: It supports flexbox